# Dell v305w prints skewed lines via wifi, fine on cable

Tags: wireless-networking, printer

When I print via the USB cable on my Dell v305w (which is also a scanner), everything is perfectly fine.

However, when I print via WiFi, typically three lines on the page are skewed.

Note:

[image: test page from printer via wifi]

Here in detail:

[image: close up of skewed lines]

If you look at the print that was done via the USB cable, it looks perfect:

[image: test page from printer via cable]

Any ideas as to what's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you saying that's reproducible 100% of the time!? That's nuts--props to whoever figures _this_ one out.

Comment: @NReilingh Yes, reproducible 100% of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I should have tried this first.  I completely uninstalled the driver, then reinstalled the newest version (it was over 70mb, yes) and now it prints fine wirelessly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the printer processor's data type:

Windows 7: Devices and Printers -> Right click printer -> Printer properties -> Advanced -> Printer Processor

Select LEMF for 'Default data type' (this is the same type as the USB is interface is using).